# XPath expression of xslt

Tags: xslt, xquery

I have a question about if statemnt for xslt if statement
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3c5/38
Here is a link to mine html structure and xslt code.
I do not understand why if statemnt is called only once however i have several circumstances at which statement can be called.
P.S.
Sorry for the wrong first code. Somehow it has shared the wrong one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<html>` element is in a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. So you have to declate it in your XSLT file and on all of the elements using it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<?startSampleFile ?>
<!-- xq61.xsl: converts xq60.xml into xq62.xml -->

  <xsl:template match="/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/xhtml:table">
      <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr">

        <xsl:value-of select="xhtml:td" />
        <xsl:if test="xhtml:td[1] != 'skip'">
            <xsl:call-template name="first_column" /> 
        </xsl:if>   
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

<?endSampleFile ?>

    <xsl:template name="first_column">

        I am here

    </xsl:template>

<!-- Copy the other nodes -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

P.S.: You changed your code after I first retrieved the XSLT and XML files. This is against the rules of SO. Include the current state of your code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's only being called 1 time because the match='/' only matches the root element in the XML.

This template is never run

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>

</xsl:template>
```